# Set default values of brushed data on x-axis with dates

Tags: vega-lite, deneb

I am working with the Overview and Detail Vega-Lite sample at https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_overview_detail.html

I am trying to set default values for the brushed data on the Overview Chart x-axis.

[image: Default selection]
[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)

I have done this for a point selection and dates [like this](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_index_chart.html):

```
      "params": [{
        "name": "index",
        "value": [{"x": {"year": 2008, "month": 2, "date": 1}}],
        "select": {
          "type": "point",
          "encodings": ["x"],
          "on": "mouseover",
          "nearest": true
        }
      }],
```

But I can't seem to get the syntax right for a time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array for the specified "X" `value`. You can go to whatever timeunit level you want.

```json
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "brush", 
          "value": 
            {"x": [{"year": 2007, "month": 7},
                   {"year": 2009, "month": 6}]}
          ,
          "select": {
            "type": "interval", 
            "encodings": ["x"]
          }
        }
      ],
```

[image: Working chart]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOOMQAZTlKBGIgAvkuJQ5UNWgDaoTHUFx9AETh1Gj0lAHcaZXo0ABYADlMlZG0Aa30kbTgUJThZJ2UaWTI0UAAPYpAAMxo4QWV9VUxfJUwATxxfdEaEHDZtJBCQaH6O0GU2ZALynHSkBH0mbQYIGDt7ECQSmghyr0wffVWlFvKqmrr0HG0aKCaQVvb9AEcGJFldtRpSVftPbw6QADypG0xGqoUUIHCkRWqDiCQwcBoZCwaAAbPCkql0OlMhDpn0ENtUB4QLJZv8FksVg5+gwRiAysTQC1Mto0AAmcwAdkSciiqC5PxALPSHPMAE5eW8YajbABdNYQGpwKCYHZtf4FRog-oQnJ5ApkIluBkgBXy7K5Nj5QrlRmgU61epqW73f5dHp9PRrY6aSrVJ0XK43CFup4vN50D5fJQbLY7a7JADCbAYbzQAGYlGQrucKv0lbYi-LbEA)